# Mediaplayer stop is not working

Tags: android

I have got a MediaPlayer object as class attribute.

```
    MediaPlayer mp;
```

Then I use them in my onCreate method -

```
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.num1);
    mp.start();
```

Then I try to stop it from one of my buttons clicklistener like this -

```
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);     
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopSound();
            startActivity(new Intent(Five.this, Four.class));
            finish();

        }
    });
}

public void stopSound(){
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
        mp.stop(); 
    }
}
```

but the stop does not work.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You've already released the MediaPlayer instance. It's gone. You can't call stop() on it after you release it. If you plan to resume the sound, just remove the release() call. If you want to destroy the MediaPlayer (e.g. create a new one later with MediaPlayer.create()), remove the stop() call. You should read over [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) pretty thoroughly; the MediaPlayer class is pretty complex. You need to understand the different states and when you can and cannot call certain methods.

Answer (score 2):

In some android versions, just some ones,  i had a similar issue in one app streamming radio, it worked it with:

```
    try{
        if(mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
        mp = new MediaPlayer();  //I needed this, maybe you dont hac
    }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("I can't believe you get here !");
    }
```

Comment: any idea how much it will impact to create mp obj here..assume if it's quick process to start and stop.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call release before stop

have a look at the lifecycle here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Ok...i removed the release method and called stop. Still no difference :(

Comment: is mp null? it should throw an exception if you try to call mediaplayer methods from an invalid state. try putting a try catch there (plus logging with log.d) and post the results from logcat

Comment: no mp is not null. 
Let me explain again. I am trying to stop the mediaplayer when I click next button. There i am trying to check for mp!=null and then call mp.stop() which does't work. 
I also tried doing this in onDestroy Method as shown in the API demo :(
I am sure i am doing something silly.

Comment: please post the output of log.d("Is mediaplayer playing", mp.isPlaying());